# Regex To Match Parts of Address

Tags: regex, webharvy

```
Shante LaGarde 01718234
Hobby Unit
123 AB 890
Marlin, Texas 76661`
```

Can someone please advise expressions to extract parts of the above from Hobby Unit to the ZIP code in separate lines.

I was able to extract the first line using `(?:\r\n?|\n){2}(.+)` but struggling to extract the other parts of the address.

Would be using the ReGEX in WebHarvy (.NET) https://www.webharvy.com/articles/regex.html

Comment: So, what do you need to match exactly? You may use several groups using your own pattern - [`^(?:\r\n?|\n){2}(.+)(?:\r\n?|\n)(.*)(?:\r\n?|\n)(.*)(?:\r\n?|\n)(.*)`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%28%3f%3a%5cr%5cn%3f%7c%5cn%29%7b2%7d%28.%2b%29%28%3f%3a%5cr%5cn%3f%7c%5cn%29%28.*%29%28%3f%3a%5cr%5cn%3f%7c%5cn%29%28.*%29%28%3f%3a%5cr%5cn%3f%7c%5cn%29%28.*%29&i=%0d%0a+Shante+LaGarde+01718234%0d%0a+Hobby+Unit%0d%0a+123+AB+890%0d%0a+Marlin%2c+Texas+76661)

Comment: Thanks, Wiktor. I am looking to match parts of the address from the second line (excluding the empty line at first) to the ZIP

Comment: So I am looking to match the Unit, the street, city, state and zip

Comment: That does not seem feasible. How can a regex know it is not a city name but a street name?